Airflow: Requesting run_id during a manual trigger
Context
I have created an Airflow DAG aimed at processing data dumps. Each dump has a unique ID, and I wish for this ID to correspond to the run_id during manual triggering of the DAG. Essentially, this allows me to ensure the uniqueness of the processing for each dump while specifying the dump to be processed.
Question
Is it possible to force the user to specify the run_id in the DAG configuration parameters?
Current behavior
Currently, the run_id is optional and is automatically generated by Airflow if not specified when triggering the DAG.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Use rules in your CI/CD to enforce this in your DAGs.

As for now (Airflow 2.9) it is not possible to force specify DagRun.run_id in the UI/Rest API/CLI
There is some close related but not exact issue/discussion exists for changing the behaviour of Run ID mechanism:

https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/33945
https://github.com/apache/airflow/discussions/34064

For now if you need to force to specify run_id I would recommend to create some middleware between Airflow and triggering DAG, e.g. manually run this DAG by the Airflow REST API and check dag_run_id before send request to the API
